# Include a name attribute while adding to an <ol>

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I'm working on a website that has a dynamic list in it and I want to be able to access individual elements in the list.

Is there a way to add a name to each element when using `appendChild()`?

This is my function:

```
function addOrder(theName, thePrice) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var t = document.createTextNode(theName);
    li.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("cart").appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: `li.name = 'nameHere'`

Comment: You should probably use `li.innerHTML = theName;`

Comment: of course, you're now dealing with invalid HTML ... as the name attribute is (technically) only valid for `<a>, <applet>, <button>, <form>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, <map>, <meta>, <object>, <param>, <select>, and <textarea>` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean adding a name or data to each element so you can access it at some later time in JS? If so you would want a data-attribute, which you set by using the dataset property.

```
function addOrder(theName, thePrice) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");

  // Add a data attribute with name of data-name and value of theName:
  li.dataset.name = theName;

  var t = document.createTextNode(theName);
  li.appendChild(t);
  document.getElementById("cart").appendChild(li);
}
```

In future code you can now look for a list item with a specific name by using something like this: `document.querySelectorAll("[data-name='some name']");` or you could get all list items and filter them:

```
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll("#cart li");
const nameIWantToFind = 'some name';
const foundName = Array.from(listItems).filter(item => item.dataset.name === nameIWantToFind);
```

Also, as others have said, you don't need to use `createTextNode`. You can use `textContent` instead. Others have suggested `innerHTML` which will work, but isn't needed if you only plan to insert text, and `textContent` should have slightly better performance. Here is how you would rewrite the function:

```
function addOrder(theName, thePrice) {
  // It's neater to put your DOM elements in variables at the top of the function
  var cart = document.getElementById("cart");

  var li = document.createElement("li");

  // Add the text inside the `li` element:
  li.textContent = theName;

  // Add a data attribute with name of data-name and value of theName:
  li.dataset.name = theName;

  // Append the `li` element to the `#cart` using the variable we defined at the top of the function:
  cart.appendChild(li);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Definitely!**

Here you go:

**== UPDATED with ES6 ==**

```
function addOrder(theName, thePrice) {
   // Select your `ul` element
   const list = document.querySelector("#cart");
   // Create `li` element
   const li = document.createElement("li");
   // Add your dynamic HTML to the `li`
   li.innerHTML = theName;
   // Append your `li` to your `ul`
   list.appendChild(li);
}
```

Have any concerns? *Feel free to comment!*